# Indentation graphviz dot in case of HTML like labels

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a, generated, UML diagram and render this with `dot` (tests are done with version 7.0.5), the results are OK nut when I want to split the lines in the graph the rendering is not as I like it.
I tried to get the results with the HTML like labels in `dot` but this looks worse (I know that the dot manual, https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html, states it has only limited possibilities).

The original (node2) and adjusted / test (node3) code:

```
digraph "Class" {
  bgcolor="transparent";

  edge [fontname=Helvetica,fontsize=10,labelfontname=Helvetica,labelfontsize=10];
  node [fontname=Helvetica,fontsize=10,shape=record,height=0.2,width=0.8];

  Node2 [label="{FClass\n|# m_trackingEnabled\l|+ FClass()\l+ InsertRenderMaterial\lInsertRenderMaterial()\l+ InsertRenderMaterialDelete\lInsertMaterial()\l+ setTrackingEnabled()\l}",
    height=0.2,width=0.4,color="grey75", fillcolor="white", style="filled"];

  Node3 [label=<
    <TABLE CELLBORDER="0" BORDER="0">
      <TR><TD COLSPAN="2" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0">FClass</TD></TR>
      <HR/>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0">#</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0">m_trackingEnabled</TD></TR>
      <HR/>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">FClass()</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"  CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="LEFT" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">InsertRenderMaterial<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>InsertRenderMaterial()</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"  CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">InsertRenderMaterialDelete<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>InsertMaterial()</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"  CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">setTrackingEnabled()</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
   >,height=0.2,width=0.4,color="grey75", fillcolor="white", style="filled"];
}
```

the resulting image (left original, right adjusted / test):

[image]

Problems:

- original

  - in case of splitting the line (second and third "Insert") the new line starts at the beginning. This is logical as we have just one string, but far from nice in our case.
- adjusted

  - indentation of splitted lines is depending on the length
  - (minor) horizontal ruler should be stretch full box

Note:

- I used here Helvetica as font, but the user can choose any font he likes so just adding some spaces in the original doesn't give the right result (unless....)
- the initial character of the description will be one of `+`, `#`, `-`, `*`, `~`.

Any solution / suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small changes to both **record** & **html** versions:

to **record**:

- added 3 non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) after **\l** line break to shift right (align)

to **html**:

- added `<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>` to the end of every line segment (seems to apply to preceeding text)
- set html node shape to **plain** to extend **HR** to edges
- set **cellpadding="1"** (just because)

```
digraph "Class" {
  bgcolor="transparent";

  edge [fontname=Helvetica,fontsize=10,labelfontname=Helvetica,labelfontsize=10];
  node [fontname=Helvetica,fontsize=10,shape=record,height=0.2,width=0.8];
  
  //
  // added 3 non-breaking spaces (&nbsp;) after \l line break to shift right (align)
  //
  Node2 [label="{FClass\n|# m_trackingEnabled\l|+ FClass()\l+ InsertRenderMaterial\l&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;InsertRenderMaterial()\l+ InsertRenderMaterialDelete\l&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;InsertMaterial()\l+ setTrackingEnabled()\l}",
    height=0.2,width=0.4,color="grey75", fillcolor="white", style="filled"];

  //
  // added <BR ALIGN="LEFT"/> to the end of every line segment (seems to apply to preceeding text)
  // set html node shape to plain to extend HR to edges
  // set cellpadding="1" (just because)
  //
  Node3 [shape=plain  label=<
    <TABLE CELLBORDER="0" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="1" >
      <TR><TD COLSPAN="2" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0">FClass</TD></TR>
      <HR/>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0">#</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left" CELLPADDING="1" CELLSPACING="0">m_trackingEnabled</TD></TR>
      <HR/>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"  CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left"  CELLSPACING="0">FClass()</TD></TR>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"   CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="LEFT"  CELLSPACING="0">InsertRenderMaterial<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>InsertRenderMaterial()<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"   CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left"  CELLSPACING="0">InsertRenderMaterialDelete<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/>InsertMaterial()<BR ALIGN="LEFT"/></TD></TR>
      <TR><TD VALIGN="top"   CELLSPACING="0">+</TD><TD VALIGN="top" ALIGN="left"  CELLSPACING="0">setTrackingEnabled()</TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
   >,height=0.2,width=0.4,color="grey75", fillcolor="white", style="filled"];
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the `&npsp;` version will work in all fonts, as written in the note: "I used here Helvetica as font, but the user can choose any font he likes so just adding some spaces in the original doesn't give the right result ". I'm not sure that everywhere the width of `&nbsp;` is equal to the width of e.g. `#`.

Comment: The result with HTML as given by you looks very good. I used now dot version 7.0.5 but not all users will use this version. `dot` has been quite quiet for a while and fortunately (:-) ) about 2 years ago (?) new versions started to appear. It looks like that in version 2.47.1 it nicely works but in version 2.38.0 (a long standing version, for me) it doesn't ( error: "Warning: using box for unknown shape plain"). Quite a few systems will still use older versions of `dot`, is it known when the "plain" possibility has been introduced (version and date)? The `<BR>` solves the major problem.

Comment: node shape documentation: `NOTE: For releases later than 9 September 2014, one can use shape=plain`.  Maybe `plaintext` or `none` would work.

Comment: The `plaintext` and `none` versions look good. In an image viewer I see a "white" border around it but it might be transparent and I have to look in the real application how this will look like in different situations. The dot 2.38.0 (20140413.2041) is just too old.